# How Do I Specify Certain Products To Only Be Purchasable and Shipped To UK

Tags: product, shipping

I have a brand of products which we are not allowed to ship outside of the UK. Is it possible in the back-office of Magento to specify a brand/category to ONLY show the UK shipping options (i.e. preventing customers from placing the order to an international country)?

I would still like the rest of my brands/categories to be shippable internationally. I just need to exclude 1 brand/category.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate store for UK ( or any country required ) and add those products in that store.

Go to

```
system->configurations->General->Web
```

select only UK from Allowed country list.